# Making a parameter of an URL persistent

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a token that needs to be saved in the URL after the user has logged and for it to be used for every request that the client makes to the API. The problems occurs whenever i try to send a new request after i have logged in.

This is my Log In which also contains the assignment of the token

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LogIn(User user)
        {
            try
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(user.Username + ":" + user.Password)));

                HttpResponseMessage clientTask = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44324/api/Auth/LogIn");

                if (clientTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string txtBlock = await clientTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var tokenObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SessionAPI>(txtBlock);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;

                    Request.RouteValues.TryAdd("token", tokenObject.Token);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", Request.RouteValues);
                }
                else
                    return View("LogInIndex", user);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("An Error has occured" + e);
            }
        }
```

The Token is assigned but on the second request is not present

Example of another Action

```
[HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ListAll()
        {
            try
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("AuthToken", "Token " + Request.RouteValues["token"]);

                HttpResponseMessage clientTask = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:44324/api/User/ListAll");

                if (clientTask.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    string txtBlock = await clientTask.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(txtBlock);

                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = null;


                    return View("ListAll", users);
                }
                else
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("An Error has occured" + e);
            }
        }
```

My Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoServiceShopClient.Filters;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace AutoServiceShopClient
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddHttpClient();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Auth}/{action=LogInIndex}/{param?}");

                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "Token",
                    pattern: "{controller=Auth}/{action=LogInIndex}/{token}/{param?}");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Routing is for the current request, so you will not get the previous route value.Instead of you could use session/cookie to make it.Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#state-management

Comment: I know that i can save the value of the token in a cookie/Session but as a part of my assignment i have to save it in the URL